# Python Searching a Nested list recusively unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive algorithm that searches a nested array for an integer.

This is what I currently have as my code, I have added the print statement to see what it does every iteration. And the output shows that it should return `True` at some point, even though it doesn't.

```
def nestedListContains(lst, n):
    for i in lst:
        print(f'i: {i}, n: {n}')
        if type(i) == list:
            nestedListContains(i, n)
        elif int(i) == int(n):
            return True
    return False


print(nestedListContains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 3)) # Should return True
print(nestedListContains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 5)) # Should return False
```

Output:

```
i: 1, n: 3
i: [2, [3], 4], n: 3
i: 2, n: 3
i: [3], n: 3
i: 3, n: 3 # This iteration should return True!
i: 4, n: 3
False

i: 1, n: 5
i: [2, [3], 4], n: 5
i: 2, n: 5
i: [3], n: 5
i: 3, n: 5
i: 4, n: 5
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` when you call your recursive function as that will be the one that returns `True`

```py
def nestedListContains(lst, n):
    for i in lst:
        print(f'i: {i}, n: {n}')
        if type(i) == list:
            return nestedListContains(i, n)
        elif int(i) == int(n):
            return True
    return False


print(nestedListContains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 3))  # True
print(nestedListContains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 5))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value of the call to `nestedListContains(i, n)`, otherwise the value returned will be discarded, and the loop will continue, until `return False` is reached:

```
def nestedListContains(lst, n):
    for i in lst:
        print(f'i: {i}, n: {n}')
        if type(i) == list:
            return nestedListContains(i, n)
        elif int(i) == int(n):
            return True
    return False
```